# Styling - setting appearance of text when td is changing its width with its animation

Tags: html, css, animation, show-hide

Recently, I found out that my navigation menu has too few tabs. Therefore, I was going to hide the texts in tabs by default and let the texts appear when hovering a tab. But the texts shows instantly and even breaks the tab expanding animation.
This is what I want: [http://i.imgur.com/XEJl9sW.gif](https://i.imgur.com/XEJl9sW.gif), as well as hiding the text too.
Can someone help me with a solution please? Thanks.
PS: CSS is preferred to JS.
<strike>The words in the gif means `transformers`.</strike>

EDIT:
Thanks for @Mat' s solution.
I modified a bit so it looks much better:
https://jsfiddle.net/n80dn16o/2/

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Sorry for that, I added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set the text and the img inside an absolute block.
Find below a working exemple : https://jsfiddle.net/zh6z2jmq/11/

```
td.locale-text p{
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
}
```